# How to get a list of prime numbers in Python from a range of numbers?

Tags: python, primes

The situation is this: I am trying to get a list of numbers from a range (say 2 through 100), but I am to look at the highest number and see how many prime numbers are in that range. I cannot figure out how to get the 100 to be a variable response.

This is my code:

```
def is_prime(number):
    if isinstance(number,int) == 'False': #stops if the number is not an integer
        return
    if number <= 1: #we do not need anything less than 1 or 1
        return
    if number == 2: #we know 2 is prime, so if they want a list of primes for 2, well...
        return 2  
    for factor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5)+1,2):        
        if number % factor == 0: #if this is true, we do not want it as its not prime
            return
    else:
        if number % 2 == 0: #I was having issues with 4,6,8 showing up, so I had to do this to get rid of those
            return
        else:
            return number  #this will be a number, should be prime....

AllNumsInRange = list(range(2,100))  #The 1000 needs to be a variable. One that someone enters in and then the whole thing works. but I do not know how to do that... SQl I do, SPROCs are easy lol. This no idea.

PrimeNumber = list(filter(partial(is_not,None), list(map(is_prime,AllNumsInRange))))  #this cleans up the list, gets rid of the Nones and maps the function to the range.

print(PrimeNumber)
```

I get:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

which is correct for a hard coded number

I can get this far as long as I have a hard coded range. This does not work out when you have to use the below prompt.

```
print(allPrimesUpTo(100))
```

I have tried various ways to get `AllNumsInRange` into the function:

```
def allPrimesUpTo(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return
    if number == 2:
        return 2  
    for factor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5)+1,2):        
        if number % factor == 0:
            return
    else:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            return
        else:
            AllNumsInRange = list(range(2,number))
            PrimeNumber = list(filter(partial(is_not,None), list(map(is_prime,AllNumsInRange))))
    print(PrimeNumber)

print(allPrimesUpTo(100))
```

But I get `None` as the solution.  Which it is not, and should be:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

It's obvious I am doing something wrong, and I would like to fix this.  This is for my personal growth and I am stumped.  Also, if you could tell me how to google this, it would be helpful too, using the right vocabulary is key there and I tried multiple lists in a function, and various combos but with no luck.

Comment: Why is `for factor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5)+1,2):` in `allPrimesUpTo`? That causes the function to immediately return `None` if the range maximum (`number`) is composite.

Comment: `if isinstance(number,int) == 'False'` This will never be true, because you're comparing to a string, and isinstance does not return strings...

Comment: Just as a side note, the interface of returning `None` if the number is composite (or if there's an error) and returning the number if it is prime is a bit strange. Usually an `is_X` predicate function would return a boolean, i.e. `True` is the number is prime and `False` is the number is composite. If you used that sort of interface, you'd be able to use your function as a predicate directly. For example `filter(is_prime, AllNumbersInRange)`

Comment: You don't return anything if you get to the last `else:` block, it just prints the list. It should do `return PrimeNumber` instead.

Comment: "But I get None as the solution. Which it is not, and should be:" - This has **nothing to do with** the logic for "getting `AllNumsInRange` into the function" (by which you appear to mean, *creating* the corresponding `range` inside the function, using the `number` value to set its size. All of that logic works fine. The problem is that you are confused between the logic to determine whether one number is prime, and the logic to test multiple numbers. This can't be clearly answered, because there is not a coherent question here, because the underlying thinking is too confused.

Comment: The reason that `allPrimesUpTo` returns `None` is because there isn't any code in it, anywhere, that could cause it to return anything else (the `print(PrimeNumber)`, in particular, **does not** do such a thing; printing has **nothing to do with** returning). But all the code inside `allPrimesUpTo`, before the `AllNumsInRange = list(range(2,number))` setup, does not make any sense. it is code for testing whether `number` is prime; but we **do not care** whether `number` is prime, because `number` **is not** a specific value we're checking, but a limit on how far to check.

Comment: So to the person who wrote that if isinstance(... I did not know this. Reminder here, I am literally just three hours into a class and the moderator gave this as the challenge.  We havent even gotten to isinstance. I found it on a blog and thought that I was using number correctly, and also thought number was a number and not a string. I guess I need to know how to make the string become a number??? is that possible? SQL is so much easier. I love my SQL. I have to learn Python to do some database stuff and I am trying to learn the basics before running you know?

Comment: To the person who said you do not return anything, I was afraid I was misunderstanding that part. So, I should be returning and not printing.  I assume they are not the same thing. I will google this to figure it out.  I am trying to learn as quickly as possible for my job and I am pulling my hair out lol. But this is how I felt with other languages too. Ill figure it out with help from you all. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY I have the answer though not elegant.  I still want to try to do what was suggested.  What I wanted to do was have an input.  That input then gets checked to see if it is an integer. If not, we get an error or it stops working. If it is an integer, then have it get checked by the function. Finally, print out a list of prime numbers that the inputted number had.

This is what I came up with after 4 hours of a class. Remember, I am 4 hours into a 4 week class. So, first week. I am sure I will get much more elegant. But this does what I needed.  Thank you to itprorh66 for their suggestions.  That was super cool.

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return
    if number == 2:
        return 2  
    for factor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5)+1,2):        
        if number % factor == 0:
            return
    else:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            return
        else:
            return number
while True:
    inval = input('What is the max range number you would like to use to get all prime numbers?  ')
    try:
        number = int(inval)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(f'{inval} is not an integer.')
        
AllNumsInRange = list(range(2,int(number)))
PrimeNumber = list(filter(partial(is_not,None), list(map(is_prime,AllNumsInRange))))
print(PrimeNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you pass 100 to the function, then get to this part:

```py
for factor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5)+1,2):        
        if number % factor == 0:
            return
```

And since 100 is divisible by 4, you return. You can get rid of all that code that you already put in `is_prime` and it will work:

```py
def allPrimesUpTo(number):
    AllNumsInRange = list(range(2, number))
    PrimeNumber = list(
        filter(partial(is_not, None), list(map(is_prime, AllNumsInRange)))
    )
    return PrimeNumber
```

Now, a few things:

1. It would make more sense if `is_prime` returned True or False, then you wouldn't need to filter out those Nones.
2. You compare `isinstance(number, int)` to the string `"False"`, not boolean `False`, so it will always be False.

This could look something like this:

```py
def is_prime(number):
    if not isinstance(number, int) or number <= 1:
        return False

    if number != 2 and number % 2 == 0:
        return False

    for factor in range(3, int(number**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if number % factor == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

3. You don't need to convert a range to a list.

So this would be enough:

```py
def all_primes_up_to(number):
    return list(filter(is_prime, range(2, number)))
```

This works fine, but a more Pythonic way to do this would be to use a list comprehension:

```py
def all_primes_up_to(number):
    return [i for i in range(2, number) if is_prime(i)]
```

Comment: I am so new to this. I am taking one of the in learning classes and she is going really fast. And this is how I interpreted what she wanted. But a lot of what I am doing she hasn't even explained so I am learning from blogs. So, some of this is not mine but I probably misunderstood what they were doing and thought I could do this with what the blog people were saying. Which is why I am asking the group here since I used stackoverflow to learn TSQL and PSQL along time ago lol. You all were helpful back then.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works beautifully. I want to add more to it to get it so that if someone enters Pizza (and trust me people do this with data all the time) then it throws an error. Thank you for answering my question. I am glad that you understood what I was asking for. I also came up with another solution. Which is not elegant in the least bit. Would you look at that one?  I am going to try to combine yours with my new one! Again thank you, I thought I was losing my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are almost there but need to tweak your while loop as follows:

```
while True:
    inval = input('What number are you looking for? ')
    try:
        number = int(inval)
        break                  # Break out of the loop when input is integer
    except ValueError:
        print('This is not an integer')
        
AllNumsInRange = list(range(2,int(number)))
PrimeNumber = list(filter(partial(is_not,None), list(map(is_prime,AllNumsInRange))))
print(PrimeNumber)
```

To give you some context, the while loop will ask the user to input a number, which is a str value stored as inval.  The try section attempts to convert inval to an integer value stored as number.  If the conversion is successful, the code breaks out of the while loop and continues with the line `AllNumsInRange`.  If the conversion results in a 'ValueError' the code prints out the warning and goes back to asking for a number.

The lines beginning with `AllNumsInRange` are at the same level of indentation as the `While` statement

Comment: OOOO! This makes sense. I am having a tough time with the indenting and knowing when what happens. I get what you did here. I am going to try this. How should i have looked at this to know about where to indent?

Comment: OOOO I get what is going on here. I have fixed my error. I still had a break after the ValueError.  Thank you